# Weird hidden records when inserting in imported MariaDB database

Tags: php, mysql, insert, mariadb

I'm having this issue with an imported database.  I've imported a simple table with  36 records (the first column "id" is an integer - autoincrement), so, the records go from 1 to 36.

When I started doing an insert using PHP, it seems the inserting process goes well, but when I do a select all tables (using HeidiSQL), it shows no more than the original 36. However, if I do the same select using a php script, it shows all the record correctly (42 so far).

I did the same exercise using `select count(*) from table`, and it shows a value of 36 using HeidiSQL, and 42 using the php script.

Then, I made a manual insert in HeidiSQL, and the record was inserted correctly, and the select query in HeidiSQL showed all the records to 36,  skipping the rest and then showed the 43 record.  Any idea what could be causing this?   thanks in advance

Comment: Probably, your HeidiSQL is looking at a different copy of the database than your PHP script. (This is a common oversight people sometimes make, which can lead to this kind of thing, there aren't really any other logical explanations.). Select again using PHP and see if you can see the record you inserted via HeidiSQL, or not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just restarted HeidiSQL and the records showed up, so I assume this is some kind of bug in HeidiSQL.  Thanks.

Comment: Could be some sort of caching issue in that software, yes.